# How to access azure portal with cli

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

How to login to azure PIM with Az Cli? as per the MS doc [how to use az cli] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt)

cmd to login is `login az` which takes you to the portal, in case of Privileged identity
management being enabled i am not sure how to access the same, any inputs pls?

`Error detail: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /common/oauth2/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))`

Answer (score 2):

As of now and as per this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/privilegedidentitymanagement-root?view=graph-rest-beta) Azure CLI has no native support for Privileged Identity Management. You can use Graph Rest API

> The Privileged Identity Management (PIM) API for **Azure AD roles** is deprecated and stopped returning data on May 31, 2021. Use the [role management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/rolemanagement?view=graph-rest-beta&preserve-view=true) API and see the [migration guidance below](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/privilegedidentitymanagement-root?view=graph-rest-beta#migrate-from-pim-v2-to-pim-v3-apis).
> The Privileged Identity Management (PIM) API for **Azure resources** will be deprecated soon. Use the new [Azure REST PIM API for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/role-eligibility-schedule-requests). To migrate, see the migration guidance below.

You can raise a Feature request and share your suggestion from this [link](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community).